# How to .map correctly this array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I would like to map an array of objects. This array of objects it's dynamic, this means sometimes it has 4 objects and sometimes 20, so I need to make sure it will work no matters how many entries it has:

```
var obj = [
  {
    "key": "one",
    "value": "something"
  },
  {
    "key": "two",
    "value": "random"
  },
  {
    "key": "blue",
    "value": "chicken"
  },
  {
    "key": "orange",
    "value": "sportsman"
  }
];
```

I need to pass this objects into one to send it through a POST call that should match this format:

```
form: {
        'one': 'something',
        'two': 'random',
        'blue': 'chicken',
        'orange': 'sportsman'
      }
```

I can access to item.value but IDK why I can't item.key:

```js
    var obj = [
      {
        "key": "one",
        "value": "something"
      },
      {
        "key": "two",
        "value": "random"
      },
      {
        "key": "blue",
        "value": "chicken"
      },
      {
        "key": "orange",
        "value": "sportsman"
      }
    ];
    
var combined = obj.map(function combined(item) {
  return {
      item.key: item.value
  };
})

console.log(combined);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't return an object from your callback function. Return an array of the key and value, then use `Object.fromEntries()` to turn this into a single object with those keys and values.

```js
var obj = [{
    "key": "one",
    "value": "something"
  },
  {
    "key": "two",
    "value": "random"
  },
  {
    "key": "blue",
    "value": "chicken"
  },
  {
    "key": "orange",
    "value": "sportsman"
  }
];

var combined = Object.fromEntries(obj.map(item => [item.key, item.value]));

console.log(combined);
```

Comment: In terms of speed and performance, between your answer and the answer #2 with both of ways, which one would you choose? Thanks.

Comment: the `for` loop will almost certainly be much faster

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68942844/benchmarks-array-reduce-map-and-filter-a-temporary-issue for some recent discussion of performance of different looping methods

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You can't use a map here because the map will return a new array. You can achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var obj = [
  {
    key: "one",
    value: "something",
  },
  {
    key: "two",
    value: "random",
  },
  {
    key: "blue",
    value: "chicken",
  },
  {
    key: "orange",
    value: "sportsman",
  },
];

const result = obj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { key, value } = curr;
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also do this using for..of loop

```js
var obj = [{
    key: "one",
    value: "something",
  },
  {
    key: "two",
    value: "random",
  },
  {
    key: "blue",
    value: "chicken",
  },
  {
    key: "orange",
    value: "sportsman",
  },
];

const result = {};

for (let o of obj) {
  result[o.key] = o.value;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: In terms of speed and performance which of the ways would you choose? Thank you for both answers, helped a lot!

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such performance difference between both of these snippets. You can use any one of these.